# Sinon spy use two different callback signatures

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, sinon

```
const sinon = require('sinon')

function test (use) {

  use(function (req, res) {
    return true
  })

  use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    return false
  })

}

test()
```

I need a way to create a spy where the first time the `use` function is going to be used it's passed `sinon.spy({}, {})` and the second time it needs to use `sinon.spy(false, {}, {}, () => {})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand, but do you mean something like this?

```
let stub = sinon.stub();

stub.onCall(0).callsArgWith(0, {}, {});
stub.onCall(1).callsArgWith(0, false, {}, {}, () => {});

test(stub);
```

`use` is a Sinon stub that, on its first call, calls the first argument with `{}, {}` as arguments, and something similar for the second call.